# Effects of wartime rationing on British life expectancy?

Tags: economic-history, demographics

From *The Economist* (23 May 2020):

> In Britain during the 1940s life expectancy shot up by seven years, thanks to a wartime rationing system that ensured everyone had nourishing (if dull) food.

I was surprised to read the above sentence. It seems to suggest that the wartime rationing system was the leading or even sole *cause* of a seven-year increase in life expectancy in Britain in the 1940s.

So, I wonder if there have been actual studies by economists/demographers/social scientists on the effects of wartime rationing on British life expectancy and what they say?

---

[Dataset](https://www.closer.ac.uk/data/life-expectancy-birth/) from CLOSER:

[image]